# How do I indicate that a class doesn't support certain operators?

Tags: c++, error-handling, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

I'm writing a class that represents an ordinal scale, but has no logical zero-point (eg time).
This scale should permit addition and substraction (`operator+`, `operator+=`, ...) but not multiplication.

Yet, I always felt it to be a good practice that when one overloads one operator of a certain group (in this case the math operators), one should also overload all the others that belong to that group. In this case that would mean I should need to overload the multiplication and division operators also, because if a user can use `A+B` he would probable expect to be able the other operators.

Is there a method that I can use to throw an error for this at compiler time? The easiest method would be just no to overload the operators `operator*`, ... yet it would seem appropriate to add a bit more explaination than `operator* is not know for class "time"`.

Or is this something that I really should not care about (*RTFM user*)?

Comment: I've used `+` with `std::strings` for ages, and never -not even once- I expected to do `*` nor `-` with them...

Comment: @John Dibling: What's `"a" * "b"` or `"a" - "b"` in _Ruby_?

Comment: A syntax error.  But `"a" * 5` isn't.

Comment: @John Dibling: What's `"a" + 5` in _Ruby_? And `std::string("a") + 5` in _C++_? ...see my point?

Comment: @K-ballo:  I'm not trying to argue with you or disprove your point.  I was more just chatting by the SO watercooler.  Having tried Ruby, I can see how some programmers might expect those opeators to do something.  That's really all I was trying to say.

Comment: In general you could define `operator*(T, size_t)` for any type `T` that has an `operator+(T,T)`. Multiplication by repeated addition. You'd also probably want `T` to have a value `Zero`, with the property that `Zero + t == t` for all `t`, and hence it's reasonable to define `t * 0 == Zero`. For strings, that would be the empty string `std::string("")`. C++ happens not to do this, and Ruby does, but it would be no great effort for C++ to do it too. I'm not clear what the questioner means by `operator*` though -- multiplying two times together, or multiplying a time by something else.

Comment: I don't think that grouping addition and multiplication makes sense. Not even addition and subtraction. What makes sense is that if you provide `operatorX` you should also provide `operatorX=` (if it can be made more efficient than the former), additionally you if you provide `==` you should provide `!=` (implemented in terms of the former), `operator<` can be sometimes matched with `operator>`, sometimes even with `operator<=`, but that depends on the domain... in general the answer is that you should overload those operators that make sense in the *domain* of the problem.

Comment: @dribeas: "if you provide `operatorX` you should also provide `operatorX=`" -- for mutable types only, of course. But then, in C++ people do tend to write mutable types, perhaps because value semantics are convenient for the user. And I'd say that if you can implement `X=` then you should, even if it's no more efficient. Again that's for user convenience, there may be exceptions when your class is only intended for a limited audience. It's annoying to have to write `a = a + b`, just because there's no fast way to do `+=`. `int` is an example of a type where `+=` is no more efficient!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Yet, I always felt it to be a good practice that when one overloads
>   one operator of a certain group (in this case the math operators), one
>   should also overload all the others that belong to that group.

Wrong. The only groups are things like `+` and `+=`- and then *maybe* `-` and `-=`. "Arithmetic operators" in general is not a group. Consider something like `std::string`.

Comment: To be fair, using `+` on strings is a bit silly from a conceptual point of view. Concatenation D-style makes more sense.

Comment: Arithmetic operators **are** a group.  Just not one that applies to non-arithmetic data.

Answer (score 8):

Implementing an operator just to signal that is not implemented seems contrived. If anything, you could define it as a `private` member function and place a `static_assert` in it that shows a compiler error if someone (maybe a friend) tries to use it.

The best solution when an operator is not implemented: to not implement it.

Answer (score 2):

Short version: there are mathematical structures which have addition but not multiplication, so don't worry about it. Overload the operators that make sense for the mathematical structure you're representing. If someone tries to multiply together two times, then the error `no match for operator* in ...` should make sense to any C++ programmer. If you think they'll be genuinely puzzled why they can't multiply two times, you could expand in the documentation. I don't think it's really the compiler's job to know *why* an operator makes no sense for a given class, and express that in error messages.

Long version: roughly speaking, the mathematical term for a set that has the "arithmetic operators" `+` and `-` is a *group* (and normally you wouldn't use the symbol `+` for a group operator unless the operator is commutative, hence an *Abelian group*). A set that has multiplication but not addition can be a group too, provided you leave `0` out of the set. Addition and multiplication are structurally similar -- the important difference is that multiplication usually admits at least one element with no inverse (`0`), whereas addition usually doesn't.

`+` is also occasionally used as the symbol for things like addition in the natural numbers, sequence concatenation, or even set union, where elements generally don't have an inverse. In that case you don't even have a group, just a binary function, you won't define unary `-`, and you might not define binary `-` either. In such cases, arguably `+` is a bad choice of operator, but it's too late to save `std::string`.

If your group with `+` and `-` has `*` as well, and satisfies certain conditions concerning the relationship between `+` and `*`, then it's a *ring*, or a *field* if every element except the additive identity has a multiplicative inverse (and hence it has a well-behaved `/`).

On the subject of time, it's often useful to consider two distinct concepts: an absolute time and a duration. You can add together two durations (to give a duration), or an absolute time and a duration (to give an absolute time), but it's meaningless to add together two absolute times (what's "last Monday plus next Thursday"?).

It's not entirely coincidence that this behavior is similar to the operators defined on pointers (in place of absolute times) and integers (in place of durations). You can do `(char*)0 + 0`, but you can't do `(char*)0 + (char*)0`. So absolute times don't have an additive `operator+(abstime, abstime)`, but could have `operator+(abstime, duration)`.

Durations are like numbers, but they have a physical dimension. It makes sense to multiply a duration by a dimensionless number (`2.4 * 3s == 7.2s`), but only rarely to multiply together two durations, and when you do the result is not a duration since its units are seconds-squared.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the overloaded operator but do not implement it. At compile time the linker will kick up a fuss.

Comment: Or, you know, don't declare it. Then the compiler will kick up a fuss and tell you exactly where you went wrong.

Comment: @MagnusHoff - If you do not declare it, the compile can try to do a conversion implicitly to find something that would work.

Answer (score -1):

Edit:
I noticed you wanted it to be called if it was used, Then it would be best to leave it unimplemented or maybe use the assert command for a runtime error.

```
assert("Message");
```

Comment: That would display an error when the header is included, not when the operator is used.

Comment: True, I just assumed that when I saw compile time error, Editing my answer now.